# Python: Finding nearest integer value to specific integer

Tags: python

I'm trying to add an algorithm to my script that would find the nearest integer value from few variables, so for example:

```
int = 700
value1 = 400
value2 = 500
value6 = 600
```

How can I make a script that gets `value6` as the nearest value from all the value variables?

Comment: Are you looking for the closest *value* or the closest *variable*? If it's the closest *variable* you'll probably either need to store things in a dictionary, or need to use a series of if/elif/else statements.

Comment: @ShellRox, what if your int was 450?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) with an appropriate key function, e.g. the [abs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs) of the difference to `i` (which you really shouldn't name `int`):

```
i = 700  # don't shadow built-in name int
values = (value1, value2, ...)  # consider using a list/tuple from the beginning
nearest = min(values, key=lambda v: abs(i-v))

> nearest
600
```

Comment: It worked, in python2 defining value with int was not a problem though.

Comment: @ShellRox, try `int("1")` after doing `int = 700`

Comment: @ShellRox it is possible, but not recommended. Once you introduce your local `int` variable, you can no longer use the 'real' `int` :(

Comment: Thanks, i just used int for example, didn't knew about that.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in *log n* time if you keep the numbers in order and [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html)

```
i = 540
value1 = 400
value2 = 500
value6 = 600
lst = [value1, value2, value6]

from bisect import bisect
ind = bisect(lst, i, hi=len(lst) - 1)

print(min((lst[ind], lst[ind - 1]), key=lambda x: abs(x-i)))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! but i think there is easier solution for basic use.

Comment: This only really improves performance, however, if the values are ordered from the get-go (which is likely). Actively putting/keeping them in order and bisecting is at least *n log n*.

Comment: @schwobaseggl,  it would be *n log n* if we were inserting to keep lst ordered, it could not be any worse than that,  If the only thing changing is `i` then this would be considerably more efficient  for large data sets

Answer (score 2):

As a relative beginner to python I feel sure this could be improved. The other answers are great but only return the nearest value *under* the input when there are two values equally distant.

(above edited for clarity in response to Padraic Cunningham)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

values = (100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700)
i = 245
nearest_under = min(values, key=lambda v: abs(v-i))
nearest_over = min(values, key=lambda v: abs(v-i) and v<i)

under_distance = i - nearest_under
over_distance = nearest_over - i 

if (under_distance == over_distance):
        nearest = (nearest_under, nearest_over)
elif under_distance < over_distance:
        nearest = (nearest_under, )
else:
        nearest = (nearest_over, )

print (nearest)
```

Comment: Yeah good stuff man, this should be the top answer, as it works for most cases. The only thing I can say is that your code is returning a tuple, it should just return a value. Also the variable names are a bit hard to understand, but all in all, great solution.

Comment: Good point about the variable names, I was being lazy and have edited the code with better names. 

Returning a tuple was done for the case of equi-distance and then consistency.

Comment: *The other answers are great but only return the nearest value under the input* Which answers don't consider when the closest value is higher?

Comment: Bad phrasing I think. I'll edit the answer to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `min`-function with key-argument:

```
values = [400, 500, 600]
int = 700
nearest = min(values, key=lambda v: abs(v-int))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this longer way, for learning purposes I guess:

```
    values = [400, 500, 600]
    i = 700

    candidates = []
    for value in values:
        candidates.append(abs(i-value))

    closest_index = candidates.index(min(candidates))
    print(values[closest_index])
```